# Symfony 4 dependent dropdown choice type

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to make dependent choice type in Symfony 4.
I would like to activate ring type when ring shape is chosen, but I found that ring type is not activating even though ring shape is selected.
I put placeholder in ring type, so the placeholder text can be changed once ring shape is chosen. but it's not changing as well.
Since ring shape itself is working, I guess something is missing to connect ring shape and ring type but I have no idea how to fix this issue...

This is my form

```
/**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $finder = new Finder();
        $finder->directories()->in('html/upload/save_image/CustomRing/ring')->depth('==0');
        $dir_array = [];
        if($finder->hasResults()){
            foreach($finder as $dir){
                array_push($dir_array, $dir->getFilename());
            }
            
            $dir_array = array_combine($dir_array, $dir_array);
        }
        natsort($dir_array);
        
        
        
        $product = $this->customProductRepository->customProductFindByName();
        $productId = $product[0]->getId();
        $builder
        ->add('product_id', HiddenType::class,['data'=> $productId])
        ->add('ring_name', TextType::class)
        ->add('ring_shape', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'choices' => $dir_array,
            'placeholder' => 'test'
            ))
        ->add('price', IntegerType::class)
        
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Save']);

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event){
                $data = $event->getData();
                //dump($data->getRingShape());
                $ring_shape = $data->getRingShape();
                $this->addRingTypeField($event->getForm(), $ring_shape);
            }
        );
        $builder->get('ring_shape')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event){
                dump('dd');
                $ring_shape = $event->getForm()->getData();
                
                $this->addRingTypeField($event->getForm()->getParent(), $ring_shape);
            }
        );

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Ring::class,
        ]);
    }

    private function getRingTypeChoices(string $ring_shape):array
    {
        $finder = new Finder;
        $path = 'html/upload/save_image/CustomRing/ring/'.$ring_shape.'/';
        $finder->directories()->in($path)->depth('==0');
        $dir_array = [];
        if($finder->hasResults()){
            foreach($finder as $dir){
                array_push($dir_array, $dir);
            }
            $dir_array = array_combine($dir_array, $dir_array);
        }
        
        return $dir_array;
    }

    public function addRingTypeField(FormInterface $form, ?string $ring_shape){
        dump($ring_shape);
        $ring_type_choices = null === $ring_shape ? [] : $this->getRingTypeChoices($ring_shape);
        
        $form->add('ring_type', ChoiceType::class,[
            'placeholder' => null === $ring_shape ? 'please select ring shape first' : 'now select ring type',
            'choices' => $ring_type_choices,
            'disabled' => null === $ring_shape,
            'invalid_message' => false,

        ]);
    }
```

and this is my twig

```
{{form_start(form)}}
    {{form_row(form.ring_name)}}
    {{form_row(form.ring_shape)}}
    {{form_row(form.ring_type)}}
    {{form_row(form.size)}}
    {{form_row(form.price)}}
{{form_end(form)}}
```

and this is the controller

```
 public function AddRing(Request $request)
   {  
      $ring = new Ring();
      $ring->setName('ring');
      $form = $this->createForm(RingType::class, $ring);
      $form->handleRequest($request);

      if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
         $ring = $form -> getData();
         $doct = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
         //tell doctrine you want to save the ring
         $doct->persist($ring);
         
         //execute the queries
         $doct->flush();
         return $this->redirectToRoute('custom_ring_list');
      }

      return['form' => $form->createView()];

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with putting query

```
<script>
        var $ring_shape = $('#ring_ring_shape');
        $ring_shape.change(function(){
            var $form = $(this).closest('form');

            var data = {};
            data[$ring_shape.attr('name')] = $ring_shape.val();
            console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                data: data,
                success: function(html){
                    $('#ring_ring_type').replaceWith(
                        $(html).find('#ring_ring_type')
                    );
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```